# Two divs side by side for one page - passing content in Hugo

Tags: html, css, hugo

I want to create a landing page for my website that will consist of two sections side by side. And I cannot find a way to pass content to these sections so that I can then target them in CSS. I have tried [this](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/two-div-sections-one-markdown-file/27738/2) solution:

baseof.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ .Site.Language }}">
<head>
    <title>{{ if not .IsHome }}{{ .Title | title }} | {{ end }}{{ .Site.Title }}</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}">
    <link rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml' title="{{ .Site.Title }} RSS" href='/index.xml'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/style.css'>
    {{ with .Site.Params.favicon }}<link rel="icon" href="{{ . }}">
    {{ end -}}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ with .Params.description }}{{ . }}{{ else }}{{ .Summary }}{{ end }}">
    {{ if isset .Params "tags" }}<meta name="keywords" content="{{ with .Params.tags }}{{ delimit . ", " }}{{ end }}">
    {{ end -}}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    {{ partial "nav.html" . }}
</nav>
<main>
{{ block "main" . }}
{{- $sectionDelimiter := "<!-- section break -->" -}}
  {{- $rawContentSections := split .RawContent $sectionDelimiter -}}
  {{- if gt (len $rawContentSections) 1 -}}
    <div id="section-1">
      {{ index $rawContentSections 0 | .RenderString }}
    </div>
    <div id="section-2">
      {{ index $rawContentSections 1 | .RenderString }}
    </div>
  {{- else -}}
    <div id="content-not-split-into-sections">
      {{ .Content }}
    </div>
  {{- end -}}
{{ end }}
</main>
{{ block "footer" . }}
<footer>
    {{partial "footer.html" .}}
</footer>
{{ end }}
</body>
</html>
```

index.md

```
This is the content for the **first** section.
<!-- section break -->
This is the content for the **second** section.

This is main content.
```

but it doesn't generate the `<section>`s as expected?
[image: result]

How to do it correctly? I imagined there should be a way to do this like:

```
<main>
<section id="first">
{{ partial "firstsection.html }}
</section>
<section id="second">
{{ partial "secondsection.html }}
</section>
</main>
```

but I haven't found a way to pass content to the partials?